# How do I build ORB_SLAM3_ROS2

Tags: ros2, slam

When I'm trying to run ORB_SLAM3_ROS2 from [https://github.com/zang09/ORB_SLAM3_ROS2.git](https://stackoverflow.com), during the build process, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn9A6.png). Does anybody know how to solve this?

I've tried reinstalling OpenCV but it didn't work. I've successfully built the ORB_SLAM3 from [https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3.git](https://stackoverflow.com).